# How to deal with name collision when you try to deobfuscate weird code?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

i am reverse engineering one application now and i want an ability to patch it (extract sources, recompile and build it again). I started with JD-GUI but found very interesting obfuscation method.

All class names are the same word (lolkekcheburek) but in various case variations:

[image: Class names]

So, for JVM all classes names are fine, but when you try to extract it, Windows notifies about name collision:

[image: Name collision]

How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

By default windows is not case sensitive for the filename. If you really want to work on windows, you have to be on Windows 10 and enable case sensitivity for your specific folder with :
`fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\folder enable`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably to use an obfuscator like [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/) to "Obfuscate" the class and method names again, but it will actually name then Class1, Class2 and so on. But be aware that this might break some obfuscation techniques that rely on the stacktrace.